# How to pass Body Request passed to addOrUpdateBusinessMetadataAttributesWithResponse of a Purview Entity with azure-sdk-for-java?

Tags: java, azure-purview, azure-sdk-for-java

I'm have to update BusinessAttributes metadata in an entity in Azure Purview

By [Purview API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/add-or-update-business-metadata-attributes?tabs=HTTP#examples) I have to call:

`POST {Endpoint}/catalog/api/atlas/v2/entity/guid/{guid}/businessmetadata/{bmName}`

And send attributes to be updated in body request:

```
{
  "bizAttr1": "bizAttr1"
}
```

Documentation for [azure-sdk-for-java](https://azuresdkartifacts.blob.core.windows.net//staging/apidocs/com/azure/analytics/purview/catalog/EntityClient.htmlazure-sdk-for-java) mentions over-loaded method **addOrUpdateBusinessMetadataAttributesWithResponse**:

One having parameters: `(String bmName, String guid, RequestOptions requestOptions)`

and: `(String guid, RequestOptions requestOptions)`

They have no **BinaryData** parameter, how should Body Request JSON object be passed?